# gcloud app deploy error(Ignoring mysql2-0.3.21 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.21)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails

I'm in trouble with GAE(GoogleAppEngine) deployment.
I've done two turorial.

1. https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-sql?hl=en
2. https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage?hl=en

The first tutorial is success to deploy, but in the second tutorial, I cannot deploy `gcloud app deploy` command.
In result, I found 500 error in production application.

These are error in console screen below.

```
Step #1: Ignoring mysql2-0.3.21 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.21
Step #1: Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.2
Step #1: Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.13 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine sqlite3 --version 1.3.13
Step #1: Ignoring websocket-driver-0.7.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.7.0
```

In my local machine, I can run `bundle install`, start rails server and access it.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've resolved this problem.
The reason why I cannot deploy is that I didn't execute migration.
After `bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate` command, success to deploy!